# Elevar a la 2da potencia los elementos de un vector

Tags: java

Hola a todos quisiera saber como puedo elevar a la 2da potencia cada elemento de un vector usando el método de la clase Math.pow , porque al parecer como lo estoy haciendo , eleva la potencia como si fuera un solo numero, y no eleva a la potencia a cada elemento del  vector , además de esto necesito almacenar en otra variable el total de la suma de las potencias de cada uno de los elementos del vector.
Les dejo mi código aquí:

```java
public class Vector extends Thread{
    public static void main(String [] args) {

        int vector[] = new int [5];

        int aleatorio = (int) (Math.random()*10 )+1;
        int suma=0;
        int cuadrado;
        int  suma2=0;
        for (int x = 0; x < vector.length; x++) {
            vector[x] = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 1;
        }
        for(int i =0; i<vector.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(vector[i]);
        }
        //Esta es la suma del contenido del vector
        for(int i=0;  i<vector.length; i++) {
            suma= suma + vector[i];
        }

        // Esta es la suma de los cuadrados de cada elemento
        for(int i=0; i<vector.length; i++){
            cuadrado= (int) Math.pow(vector.length,2);
            suma2= suma2+cuadrado;
        }
    
        System.out.println(suma);
        System.out.println(suma2);
    }
}
```

Comment: No es que eleve la potencia como si fuera un solo número, ES un solo numero el que esta siendo elevado, en este caso es el tamaño del vector, fijate que en la linea cuadrado= (int) Math.pow(vector.length,2); no estas elevando el valor dentro del vector si no la cantidad total osea 5, por tanto lo que esta haciendo es (5x5)+(5x5)+(5x5)+(5x5)+(5x5), solo cambia vector.length dentro del Math.pow por vector[i]. Eso es todo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En esta parte de tu código:

```java
// Esta es la suma de los cuadrados de cada elemento
for(int i=0; i<vector.length; i++){
  cuadrado= (int) Math.pow(vector.length,2);
  suma2= suma2+cuadrado;
}
```

Estas usando `vector.length` en vez de `vector[i]`.

Lo que debes hacer es lo siguiente:

```java
// Esta es la suma de los cuadrados de cada elemento
for(int i=0; i<vector.length; i++){
  cuadrado= (int) Math.pow(vector[i],2);
  suma2= suma2+cuadrado;
}
```

Comment: Gracias amigos, que tengan excelente dia